# How to forecast the NPV of an off-shore wind-energy capital project. Why variables do I include?

Tags: macroeconomics

Currently I am in a very early stage of a thesis proposal. I am considering to forecast a confidence interval for the NPV of an off-shore wind-energy capital project.

I am looking for relevant parameters to include in my model. With my current knowledge I can come up with the following.

**Energy Prices**

The revenue comes from directly selling the generated energy, so I think it is important to take the variability of the energy prices into account.

**Discount rate**

The cash-flow revenue will be over a long term period. Let's say 20 years. I've learned that we must discount future cash-flows in order to obtain the NPV. I also see that the discount rate is constantly changing. Thus what discount factor what I use in order to discount my future cash-flows?

I think the better question is: **How can I incorporate the stochastic nature of the discount rate to calculate the NPV?**

**Other Questions**

Question: **Besides the two about what are other relevant (stochastic) parameters that can I take into account to forecast the NPV?**

I do not know very much yet, but I am very eager to learn. It's much appreciated if somebody could advise me on this matter.

Relevant (literature) sources are also more than welcome.

Comment: You need to read about project NPV. https://www.mheducation.com/highered/product/principles-corporate-finance-brealey-myers/M9781260013900.html